# Whether or not a group action on a possibly empty set is transitive if for all elements in the set, their orbits equal the set

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-set-theory, logic, group-actions

I think the parenthetical remark in [Definition 2.4 here](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~rf/groupactions.pdf) is wrong if $X$ is empty.

> If $X$ is a $G$-set and if $G · x = X$ for one (or equivalently all) $x ∈ X$, we say that $G$ acts transitively on $X$.

Why I think this is wrong:

For the first direction of one $x$ implies all $x$: The existence of an $x \in X$ implies $X$ is not empty. No problem here.

For the other direction: We could have "all $x \in X$" as holding vacuously for empty $X$. Therefore, no such $x \in X$ exists.

Do I misunderstand?

Comment: You're right. If you really want to consider action on the empty set, the definition should go with 'all'..

Comment: Merci, @Berci. You can answer if you want.

Comment: Just some suggestions on using this site: If you're referring to a small quote from a document, then rather than linking to a pdf, it's better form to copy out the quote (in this case Definition 2.4) and give a citation to where you found it. pdfs can change and become inaccessible. Also, if you think something is wrong, it's better form to explain why you think it's wrong, rather than just asking for confirmation.

Comment: I would disagree with Berci: the more useful definition is "for one", not "for all".  That is, the action on the empty set should not be considered transitive.

Comment: Hmm.. Possible.. Why not?

Comment: @Berci You have to tag using the "@"

Comment: @EricWofsey Berci says "Hmm.. Possible.. Why not?"

Comment: @AlexKruckman Great suggestions. Why not make your suggestions into rules? I edited the post. Thanks.

Comment: @Berci: It's the same reason that $1$ is not considered prime.  It's convenient for transitive actions to be those with exactly one orbit, so that every group action decomposes uniquely as a disjoint union of transitive actions.

Comment: $X$ is a $G-$ set, and a mapping is defined in general on a non-empty set, then how can $X$ be empty?

Comment: There is one mapping from the empty set.

Comment: @Berci Again, You have to tag using the "@"

Comment: @EricWofsey Berci says "There is one mapping from the empty set."

Comment: @who You can certainly define a $G$-action on the empty set! You can equivalently consider this as the unique function $G \times \varnothing \to \varnothing$ (which will automatically be associative and unital) or as the unique group homomorphism $G \to Aut(\varnothing)$.